# drop down list option value to null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a drop down list with multiple radio button values to choose from. If you don' t choose a option the value will be saved in the database as null. But if you choose an option, you can't uncheck it.  So I need a "not stated" option in the dropdown list instead, which would save the value as null in the database.

How can I in the best possible way change these settings so that I can save the value null in the database. I need to alter this code below so an extra option "not selected" value appears and when "not selected" is chosen the value null will be saved to the database

```
<%= account_pref.input "editorial_#{key}".to_sym, :as => :radio, :collection => options_for(Editorial, key.to_sym), :wrapper_html => { :class => "compact" }, :label => key.titleize  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the empty string should do it I think.

```
:collection => [['<none>','']] + options_for(Editorial, key.to_sym)
```

That worked for me with an integer field, for a string field it might be harder because option values can only be strings and there's not really a concept of null values in forms. Maybe someone knows a clever trick here but you could always sort it out in the controller:

```
def create
  @account = Account.new(params[:account])
  @account.editorial = nil if @account.editorial.empty?

  ...
end
```

Or maybe override the setter in your model to do the same thing. Either option feels a bit hack-ish, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hambend. 
I entered my code as follows;
:collection => ([['Not Stated','']] + options_for(Editorial, key.to_sym))

Which gave me an option 'Not Stated' at the top of my dropdown list, and when I selected it and saved, an empty string was saved in the database. 

This is where I'd like a "null" value to be saved instead, but the question is how?

I experimented by setting the second argument to just nil ( as in [['<none>',nil]] ), and with that setting the database saved the value 'on' for the dropdownlist for some reason. Strange.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize we were talking about a string field here. I've only used the solution I posted for id fields. Updated my answer with an added suggestion.